# Laravel: mock relationship with eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mockery

Here is my situation. I have this test `UpdateAdditionalCommandHandlerTest` which is a test for `UpdateAdditionalCommandHandler` And here is the code:

```
class UpdateAdditionalCommandHandler implements CommandHandler
{

use DispatchableTrait;

use ValidationCommandBus;

/**
 * @var AdditionalRepository
 */
protected $repository;

/**
 * @param AdditionalRepository $repository
 */
public function __construct(AdditionalRepository $repository)
{
    $this->repository = $repository;
}

/**
 * @param UpdateAdditionalCommand $command
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($command)
{
    \DB::beginTransaction();

    try{

        $oldAdditional = $this->repository->find($command->id);

        $additional = $this->repository->update(
            $command->id,
            $command->additionalTypeId,
            $command->factor,
            $command->name,
            $command->kind,
            $command->description,
            $command->hasInput,
            $command->inputLabel,
            $command->carrierFacingCost,
            $command->min,
            $command->max,
            $command->zip
        );

        $this->addMetaData($additional, $command->unitId, $command->rounding);

        if ($additional->additionalType->has_currency && !$command->currencyId) {
            throw new \Exception('Currency id missing');
        }

        //if updating currency aware to currency aware
        if ($command->currencyId && $oldAdditional->additionalType->has_currency) {

            $command = new UpdateAdditionalCurrencyCommand($command->id, $command->currencyId);

            $this->execute($command);

        }

        //if updating from non currency aware to currency aware
        if ($command->currencyId && !$oldAdditional->additionalType->has_currency) {

            $command = new CreateAdditionalCurrencyCommand($command->id, $command->currencyId);

            $this->execute($command);

        }

        \DB::commit();

        event(new AdditionalUpdated($oldAdditional, $additional));

        return $additional;

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        \Log::debug('ROLLBACk', [$e]);

        \DB::rollBack();

    }

}

/**
 * @param Additional $additional
 * @param $unit
 * @param $rounding
 */
private function addMetaData(Additional $additional, $unit, $rounding)
{
    if ($unit && $rounding) {
        //-- delete old meta
        $additional->deleteAllMeta();

        $additional->addMeta(
            'unit_factor',
            json_encode([
                'unit_id' => $unit,
                'rounding' => $rounding
            ])
        );
    }
}

}
```

And here is the test:

```
class UpdateAdditionalCommandHandlerTest extends UnitTestCase
{
    use CommandHelperTrait;

    /**
     * @test update a additional
     * @expectedException Exception
     */
    public function itShouldUpdateAdditional()
    {
        \DB::shouldReceive('beginTransaction');
        \DB::shouldReceive('commit');
        \DB::shouldReceive('rollback');

        $attributes = [
            'id' => 1,
            'additional_type_id' => 1,
            'factor' => 1,
            'name' => 'test additional',
            'description' => 'test',
            'has_input' => false,
            'kind' => 'linked',
            'input_label' => null,
            'carrier_facing_cost' => true,
            'min' => 1,
            'max' => 2,
            'zip' => '44000',
            'currency_id' => null,
            'unitId' => 1,
            'rounding' => '5up'
        ];

        $command = $this->createCommand(UpdateAdditionalCommand::class, $attributes);

        $additional = $this->makeEloquentMock(Additional::class, $attributes);
        $additional->shouldReceive('deleteAllMeta');
        $additional->shouldReceive('addMeta');
        $additional->shouldReceive('getAttribute');

        $repository = mockery::mock(AdditionalRepository::class);
        $repository->shouldReceive('find')->andReturn($additional);
        $repository->shouldReceive('update')->andReturn($additional);

        $commandHandler = new UpdateAdditionalCommandHandler($repository);

        $additional = $commandHandler->handle($command);

        $this->assertInstanceOf(Additional::class, $additional);

    }

}
```

When I run the test, it gives me the following error:

> Trying to get property 'has_currency' of non-object at
> /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/app/Domain/Additionals/Commands/UpdateAdditionalCommandHandler.php:68)

Now line no 68 is this:

```
if ($additional->additionalType->has_currency && !$command->currencyId) {
```

So it suggests that `$additional->additionalType` is null which shouldn't be the case. `Additional` class does have this relationship:

```
    public function additionalType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Phirater\Domain\Additionals\AdditionalType');
    }
```

So what is going wrong here? How to fix this? My `PHP` version is `7.3`, `Laravel` version is `5.6` and `PHPunit` version is `^7.0` with `mockery` `^1.0`

Comment: $additional->additionalType is null in your case

Comment: @Thomas yeah I know that, but it shouldn't be as it is working fine functionally but unit test failing.